# Show that $\gamma'' = \kappa_n N + \kappa_g N \times \gamma'$

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, curvature

I want to show $\gamma'' = \kappa_n N + \kappa_g N \times \gamma'$.
We assume $\gamma$ is parametrized by arc lenght. $N$ is the normal vector and $k_n$, $k_g$ are, respectively, the normal and geodesic curvatures. I know the following facts:

- $\{N, \gamma', \gamma'\times N\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$.
- $\gamma ' \perp \gamma ''$
- we can write $\gamma ''$ =A$N$ +B$\gamma ' \times N$, A and B being real constants (i.e. the coefficient along $\gamma'$ is $0$).
- $\kappa_g=\gamma''\cdot(N\times \gamma')$
- $\kappa_n = \|\gamma''\cdot N\|$

I really don't know where to begin to prove it. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Googling [Frenet's frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas) should help.

Comment: @Michał Miśkiewicz I really tried but I think I'm not going anywhere. Could you give me an actual clue on how to start?

Comment: If $u,v$ are orthonormal vectors and some vector $w$ is its linear combination $w = au+bv$, then the coefficients $a,b$ can be recovered by taking the scalar product: $a = \langle w,u \rangle$, $b = \langle w, v \rangle$. Up to some notational differences (which I cannot explain), this is what $\kappa_g$ and $\kappa_n$ give you.

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz that might be enough, if I solve it I'll update my post. Thank you